# Gathering and Filtering Necessary Post Data for a HTTP Post Requests

Tags: c#, http-post, autofill

I hope you're all well. I am trying to use C# and the request.post command to autofill a login page. I've shown the snippet of code I'm dealing with below.

My main concern currently is the 'POST DATA GOES HERE' .I'm unsure how I can gather the post-data as well as what syntax / format i would need to put it in.

I've already tried using Fiddler and Charles Proxy (HTTP Debuggers) to find anything about PostData . I did find some things I needed : User-Agent / Success Keys but those currently aren't relevant.

```css
//Send a Post request to the (URL, postdata, contenttype) - store the HTTP Response into Response 
var Response = Request.Post(LOGIN_URL, "{post data goes here}", "content type goes here `application/java`");
```

Comment: I think your postdata will be something like`var postdata = new NameValueCollection();
    postdata["username"] = "username";
    postdata["password"] = "password";`

Comment: What is Request? What library are you using? There are many ways of doing this. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)

Comment: Thank you :) For both your reply and linked tutorial both are helpful. I'm mainly hoping to have all post data inside {} instead of as variable(s) . I'm using leaf.xnet . Still hoping for information on gathering postdata if anyone thinks they can help.